# Visual Studio Excel AddIn - VB.Net - ActiveWindow.Zoom Not Working

Tags: excel, vb.net

Could you please help me understand how to use "ActiveWindow" in vb.net? It's one of the items that I am having a difficult time converting from VBA to vb.net in Visual Studio. I want the ability to zoom to a specific level on the window/tab that is currently open in excel. Thanks for your help.

```
Dim ActiveWorksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet =
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Dim Worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet =
    Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(ActiveWorksheet)

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you are dimming the variable worksheet, but for the activeWindow and zooming, wouldn't this work?

```
Dim activWind As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window
activeWind = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow
activWind.Zoom = 200
```

Comment: Thank you MacroMarc - that worked perfectly and makes sense. Appreciate the help